# Replace user created blanks with 0's

Tags: google-sheets, binary, vlookup, array-formulas

I made a binary calculator with bitwise functions (bitand, bitor, bitxor, ect.) in google sheets (yes I am aware that there are built in functions to do this, this seemed more fun). It is an 8 bit calculator, and I currently have addition and subtraction implemented. Multiplication is planned, but seems way too hard at the moment

One of the things I came across is once a calculation is done, the user has to manually 0 out the addends/minuend and subtrahend one digit at a time. I would like to optimize this process.

I can easily create a script that will input 0 into all the cells and hook that up to a button. I have a feeling that's the route I'm going to have to go. But I want to challenge myself in making cool stuff, so I want the coolest solution.

My question is: is there a way I can do this without a script attached? I've been experimenting with ARRAYFORMULA and VLOOKUP, but I don't have a clear answer yet.

Expected behavior:

User inputs their calculation. User records the answer. User selects both 8 bit binary numbers (currently residing in A1:H2) and presses backspace. Google Sheet automatically translates those blank cells to 0's.

Answer (score 1):

take a look into custom internal formatting. any text can be converted to "0"

[image]

then see shifted arrays:

```
={"", "x"}
```

[image]

[image]

formula from G9 will print "0" into H9. also, you can anytime enter value in H9 to "overwrite" the zero and after you don't need the entered value you just clear it with backspace or delete key and it will be filled with "0" again.

[image]

also, note that after you enter value in H9, G9 will error out and such error cant be suppressed so see hidden cells:

[image]

[image]

not sure if it's cool enough but it works (with compromises)

Comment: It's definitely an interesting solution. And It almost works for my problem.     

I tried using a single array formula for each addend, but there were too many circular dependencies for it to work correctly. I then did 16 individual IFERRORS and hid every other column. This gave the desired 0's. However, when I select all the numbers, and press backspace, it also deletes the formulas, even though the columns are hidden. As of right know, I don't know of any way to remove hidden columns while selecting a range

Comment: I had a thought of using SPLIT and REPT to repeat the formula 8 times, but it just gives 0 for the formula column and leaves everything else blank `=SPLIT(REPT(IFERROR({"", 0})&";", 8), ";")`.    I had to change the "x" to a 0 in order for it to work with the bitwise functions